# Change value of a uidatepicker from a button on the InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, inputaccessoryview

I have a `UIDatePicker` which is created programmatically (as the first-responder) when user taps a text-field on my view. This happens inside a for-loop, so I don't have the reference to this picker in my code. I also have a toolbar on top of the picker which is added as an `inputAccessoryView` to the picker. I have a **Done** button which resigns the first-responder. So far so good.

I want to add another button on the toolbar besides the **Done** button which will change the value of the picker. There is no `UIDatePickerDelegate` which will let me track the active picker.

I can always define class variables for each of my picker and thus save the references manually. But is there an easy way to do this where I can access the `inputView` from the `inputAccessoryView` directly?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this in some.h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
     IBOutlet UIDatePicker *picker1;
     IBOutlet UITextField *txtFld;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar;

@end
```

In some.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
 picker1=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];//frames are just for demo
 [txtFld setInputView:picker1];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(keyboardToolbar == nil) {
        keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 44)] ;
        [keyboardToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];
        NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton,doneButton1, nil];

        [keyboardToolbar setItems:itemsArray];


        [txtFld setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
        [self.view addSubview:keyboardToolbar];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}



-(void)resignKeyboard {

    [keyboardToolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [txtFld resignFirstResponder];
///do nescessary date calculation here

    }
```